# Scrapy: How do I select rowspan

Tags: scrapy

Here is my code:

```
  <tr>
      <td height="34" class="normal">4893</td>
      <td class="normal">Public Utilities Commission </td>
      <td class="normal">Investigation to Examine </td>. 
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td height="34" rowspan="2" class="normal"><a 
             href="docket/4892page.html">4892</a></td>
      <td class="normal"><p>RI Distribution Genration 
            Boardd</p></td>
      <td class="normal">2019 Renewable Energy </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="normal">The Narragansett Ele</td>
      <td class="normal">2018 Renewable Energy </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td height="34" class="normal"><a 
           href="docket/4891page.html">4891</a></td>
      <td class="normal">Kearsarge Uxbridge, LLC </td>
      <td class="normal">Renewable Energy</td>
    </tr>
```

In the 2nd `<tr>` where rowspan ="2" I want to apply the content of 1st `<td>` i.e 4892 to the next `<tr>` where there are two `<td>`.  I have tried the following, but it does not work:

```
        item['id'] = row.xpath('.//tr//td[1]//text()').extract()

        if not item['id']:
            item['id'] = row.xpath('.//[preceding- 
                                      sibling::tr//td[1]//text()').extract()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So instead of "select rowspan" you're actually looking to "select *by* rowspan".

There're several approaches you may try.

Select it when a `rowspan` exists:

```
# CSS
row.css('tr td[rowspan]::text')
# XPath
row.xpath('//tr/td[@rowspan]/text()')
```

Select it when a `rowspan` has a specific value ("2" here):

```
# CSS
row.css('tr td[rowspan=2]::text')
# XPath
row.xpath('//tr/td[@rowspan="2"]/text()')
```

See also:

- https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp
- https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp